# How to supress 'Start With' Menu in ArcPad 10.2?

Tags: vbscript, arcpad

I am fairly new to ArcPad in general and I am attempting to suppress the start with menu as seen in the attached photo. I have a script that is called in the event: onstartup, that loads the .APM I need. I find this menu unnecessary and have been looking for a solution via the APX in ArcPad Studio or via an object/keyword for that particular menu. I have searched geoNet, Stackexchange, and the ArcPad Dev Help but have come up short.

Has anyone had experience in suppressing this menu? or could point me in a more appropriate direction?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the ArcPadPrefs.apx file (in the *My ArcPad* folder) is a property called STARTUP. You can change the value for **quickstart** to set the startup behavior for ArcPad.

e.g. STARTUP quickstart="0" will show the quickstart menu.

Setting the value to -1 will disable the quickstart menu.

I hope this helps,

Hannah